# Android: fllipper view not getting flliped

Tags: android, switch-statement, gesture, viewflipper, swipe

Basically, I have a ViewFlipper that flips when I swipe my finger on it. This is the code I have in my Activity:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent) {
    switch (touchevent.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        oldTouchValue = touchevent.getX();
        break;
    }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
        float currentX = touchevent.getX();
        if (oldTouchValue > currentX) {
            ViewHelper.swapFlipperNext(vf);//helper method for flipping
            setMyProgress();//helper method to set my progress bar
        }
        if (oldTouchValue < currentX) {
            ViewHelper.swapFlipperPrevious(vf);
            setMyProgress();
        }
        break;
    }
    }
    return false;
}
```

It works perfectly except for one thing, I can flip it if my finger is on a non-view part of the screen. But if my figure swipe on some views(Since I have textviews and webviews in each page of the flipper too), the onTouchEvent doesn't get activated, so the ViewFlipper doesn't get switched, how do I fix that? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try setting the focusable attribute on your textviews and webviews to false.  basically what i think is happening is these are consuming the touch event.

EDIT: if this doesn't work, try the following

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (gestureDetector != null) {
        gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

where gestureDetector is a member variable.

see from here: [EditText not capturing ViewFlipper flings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542065/edittext-not-capturing-viewflipper-flings)

Comment: I think it may because of that too, but the problem is, I have tried to set those view's focusable to false, but they became not editable, I still need to do operations on those, besides, it still can't switch, even if I set those

Comment: Problem solved, but my flipper flips even if I drag to view my webview and other stuff in it-_-